# My .exe file shows error when i convert my python file from py to .exe

Tags: python, text-to-speech

I am able to convert this code into .exe but can't run it.
I have used cx_Freeze and pyinstaller for conversion.

```
import pyttsx3 
engine = pyttsx3.init()

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
    engine.setProperty('rate', 145) 
print('Hello sir!')
speak('Hello sir')
print('you can write or paste that you want to listen and press enter. \n')
speak('you can write or paste that you want to listen and press enter. ')
var = str(input('Paste your paragraph here\n:'))
print('Dictating your paragraph....\n\n')
speak(var)
print('Thankyou for using me')
speak('Thankyou for using me!')
engine.runAndWait()
```

please tell me how to do that ?
Or try it your self

Comment: Please say what tool you are using to do the conversion.

Comment: I have used cx_Freeze and pyinstaller as well  it does't works at all

Comment: Have you tried the instructions that come with `pyinstaller` for debugging build problems? You may have to explicitly tell `pyinstaller` where to find `pyttsx3`'s binary files.

Comment: Actually i am not able to understand what u are saying. please tell me how to do that

Comment: you should try to convert this code in .exe and tell me wether it works or not?

Comment: I will be plainer, then. *Read the `pyinstaller` documentation*. Converting a program in a dynamic language is not the simple compile step you seem to think it is.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly your Pyinstaller `.spec` file. (If you don't know what that is, you are working with the default `.spec` file.) As the docs say, "it is useful to modify the `.spec` file ... when you want to include run-time libraries that Pyinstaller does not know about".  That would include the `.dll` files that implement the SAPI5 text-to-speech engine. If you *have* modified the `.spec` file, and it isn't working, then you should post it here. Also, run your `.exe` from the command line (*not* by double-click in File Explorer) and report the error you get.

Comment: Do you have a compelling reason for wanting an `.exe` file anyway? Typically one wants that to simplify deployment but your program is clearly still in the early stages of development. The `.exe` will probably be slower to load and won't run noticeably faster. Why not just run the `.py` file?

Comment: thannks for your valuable suggestion #BoarGules